# Encourage hexadecimal over base64 for binary submissions?

Tags: discussion

I'm seeing a lot of binary-code submissions in base64 encoding. Wouldn't Hex be better, from a presentation point of view? I can read hex, I can't read base64.

Comment: after reading a little more deeply into base64 I suppose I could learn to read it. It is more readable than ASCII85.

Answer (score 2):

Personally I like hexdump format, as used in [one of my answers](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/308/3). That way, any readable stuff is actually, well, readable. :-)

Comment: Yes. That makes it somewhat more accessible. As much as can reasonably be done.

Answer (score 2):

I think both forms have their usefulness.

If the vast majority of the program consists of random binary data, a hex representation isn't going to be very useful. A base64 encoding, on the other hand, gives users the ability to test your program directly, without having to perform any manual conversion - especially if you provide a wrapper which generates the program, such as provided for [this answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/9131/4098) or [this answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/9054/4098).

For shorter answers, and those with a minimal amount of non-ascii characters, I do agree that a hex representation will be more useful.

Comment: yeah. ... what if ... there were a low-impact syntax to interject a little binary into a mostly ascii source. Sounds like a job for M4. But it would need some reconfigurable escape indicator. IIRC '@' was the latest addition to ascii (it's not part of C's execution charset), so that'd be my choice for a default escape char least likely to get in the way. ... rambling. ignore if.